# Excel - Custom label format to turn "1999Q4" into "1999"

Tags: excel

I have a column of data in the form 1999Q1, 1999Q2, 1999Q3, 1999Q4, 2000Q1, etc. I would like to show these in a graph simply as 1999 and 2000—essentially, to just use the first four characters of the cell data.

In the **Format Axis** dialog under Custom label, I've tried using `####` and `0000`, but neither format seems to have any effect on the display.

What would my custom format have to be to make **1999Q2** display as **1999**, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I don't think you can do that with custom formats.

What kind of a chart are you using? If it has a categorical x-axis (line, column, bar), then I would create another column. In that column use a formula, such as:

`=Left(A1,4)`

to get just the year numbers. Then use that column for your X-axis Labels.

An alternative would be to split the year/quarter into two columns like this:

[image: Spreadsheet showing data and chart]

Notice the x-axis layout that you get when you select A1:C9 to create the chart.